# Validate a string using regex

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I want to validate a string to check if it is alphanumeric and contains "-" and "." with the alphanumeric characters. So I have done something like this to form the regex pattern

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-]"
                                   options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                   error:&error];
NSPredicate *regexTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
BOOL valid = [regexTest evaluateWithObject:URL_Query];
```

App crashes stating that the regex pattern cannot be formed . Can anyone give me a quickfix to what am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try escaping the dash, like this: `[a-zA-Z0-9.\-]`

Comment: But . is the metacharacter ?

Comment: `-` at the end of the character class does not have to be escaped. The regex is valid. However, I'd use `^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\z` for this task.

Comment: In any regex engine I've ever dealt with, the `.` within a character class does not need to be escaped.  The `-` may, though, since it does have special meaning withing a character class (e.g `[A-Z]`).

Comment: If I escape - , The error persists @StevenDoggart

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , Any clue to what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: can u tell me how do i validate with that regex @WiktorStribiżew ? I have updated my code

Comment: @ManeeshSharma: No, without more code, I can't tell anything. I think there is some typo somewhere.

Comment: I have updated @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: You need to pass a *NSString* to the `NSPredicate`

Comment: I am passing the regex pattern ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must pass a variable of type `NSString` to the `NSPredicate` *SELF MATCHES*:

```
NSString * URL_Query = @"PAS.S.1-23-";
NSString * regex = @"[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+";
NSPredicate *regexTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
BOOL valid = [regexTest evaluateWithObject:URL_Query];
```

See the [Objective C demo](https://ideone.com/vm4Mg4)

Note that you need no anchors with the *SELF MATCHES* (the regex is anchored by default) and you need to add `+` to match one or more allows symbols, or `*` to match 0+ (to also allow an empty string).

You do not need to escape the hyphen at the start/end of the character class, and the dot inside a character class is treated as a literal dot char.

Also, since both the lower- and uppercase ASCII letter ranges are present in the pattern, you need not pass any case insensitive flags to the regex.

Comment: Let me try .! give me a second